# Weird behavior in changing objects in lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have been experimenting with dotnet core, I wrote the following piece of code that is a part of a bigger one:

```
 var account = new Account();
 account.FirstName = "Tarik";
 account.LastName = "World";
 account.Balance = 1000;

 pipelineObjects.Select(a => a.Process(account));
```

`pipelineObjects` is simply a `List<IAccountPipeline>`. `IAccountPipeline` defines a method named `void Process(Account account);`.

Each `pipelineObject`in the list of `pipelineObjects` change something in the given `Account` object. For instance,

```
public void Process(Account account) {
    account.Balance = account.Balance - (account.Balance / 10 * 100);
}
```

However, when I run the code at the top, the account object is not updated. I dumped it to the console, and what I got was the property values I used when creating the object for the first time.

But, when I used the code below in the place of `.Select(a => a.Process(account))`, I started to see that `account` is updated:

```
foreach (var pipelineObject in pipelineObjects)
{
    pipelineObject.Process(account);
}
```

At first, I suspected of the closure in the lambda expression. However, `account` variable points at an object, which I am passing the reference of it around in the lambda expression. Was I wrong? Does CLR clone the `account` object and pass it to the `.Process(account)` instead? I think this does not have anything to do with `.Select()` but the closures in .NET. Any idea why it is behaving this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is that you should be doing a foreach, not a Select.

A longer answer is that how Select works isn't really part of the LINQ contract and could in theory change at any time (or differ between providers).  Whether it is a clone or a reference you shouldn't really be counting on.  Select is for projecting, not for processing, and using it like you were attempting to is misusing it.

A technical explanation of why... Well it's because LINQ is lazy executed, and you never triggered the execution.  This should work, but again, I discourage it's use:

```
pipelineObjects.Select(a => a.Process(account)).ToList();
```

That is, if it doesn't get optimized away, because LINQ expressions aren't supposed to have side-effects, but yours does.

Comment: Yes, but why is it behaving like that? -- is my question.

Comment: I think the problem is not how `.Select()` works, but instead how closures work.

Comment: Yes but it should be okay since it captures the value that points at an object in the heap. However, how it seems to be working is different. It actually seems like copying the whole object instead and that looks weird to me.

Comment: I've added the technical why for you, which explains why it isn't working.

Comment: LOL. Pfff. It was that easy? I simply forgot of the lazy nature of IEnumerable. Thanks and marked as answer.